# Prepared Statement with subquery Gives Syntax Errror

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, prepared-statement

```
PreparedStatement amovie = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO actor_movie(actor_ID, movie_ID)"+ "select actor_ID from actor" + "where actor.surname = 'Depp', select movie_ID from movie where movie.title LIKE 'Caribbean%'");
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this query ? I digged the internet, but can't find a solution.

Error Message :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ', select movie_ID from movie where title LIKE 'Caribbean%'' at line 1
```

Comment: Spaces needed before `select` and `where`

Comment: What syntax error? Please include the exact message.

Comment: When creating a query out of multiple parts, be sure to connect them together with spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax error because you forgot `VALUES` and to enclose in parentheses the `SELECT` statements. 
Change to this:

```
PreparedStatement amovie = con.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO actor_movie(actor_ID, movie_ID) VALUES ((select actor_ID from actor where actor.surname = 'Depp'), (select movie_ID from movie where movie.title LIKE 'Caribbean%'))");
```

Comment: This time i get this error : Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: It is your table, I don't know how many rows exist with title LIKE `'Caribbean%'`. You must make sure that only 1 row is returned. My answer was about the syntax error.

Comment: You are right, i checked and there are multiple rows. I use a trigger to prevent duplicate items, but i guess it is not working. Thanks for the reply. That's solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Careful with the spaces needed between the strings concatenate

```
...movie_ID)"+ "select ...
```

Comment: Still same problem.

Comment: @forpas Yes, i did.

Comment: AFAIK, most SQL parsers will not care about the absence of spaces in this location, as the `)` is recognized as a separate token.